# How to turn a database into a timer

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to build a task queue in MongoDB to manage a relatively large (100k) number of tasks. Each task has an execute date, upon which my application should cURL a website embedded in the task object. Similar to how Google calendar can send you an e-mail reminder at time `x`; I want to go to a website with options.

I have a working model, but am not sure this is the best way to handle it. Basically, I'm querying the database every second for anything whose execute date is before `now()`; and passing it to a cURL function. This seems like a waste of perfectly good processing cycles but I'm not sure how else to handle this.

Thanks in advance,
-JWW

Comment: Is the queue being constantly changed? And are new tasks being inserted with event times that are newer than other tasks sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWally,

You can query the database once every (say) hour, retrieve every task that has <= 60min remaining, and use setTimeout to schedule the tasks after that.